# Swift ios не передает заголовок Authorization

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire, авторизация

ios отказывается передавать заголовок Authorization.
Скрин с Proxyman:
[image: Proxyman отсутствие Authorization]

```
        let accessToken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiOGZlOTQzMDlhZTYyZDQ2MjY2ODJjNzVkZWNiZmIyYjI4NDJiNjM4ZWU5NmI4YWI3MDU2YTg2YjQ3NzU1MmNjNDlhODdlNTY1ODFkNWYyOGMiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mjg0MjgwMDEsIm5iZiI6MTYyODQyODAwMSwiZXhwIjoxNjU5OTY0MDAxLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbIioiXX0.oD91WeEcOtCaeBnfvfP6td6l1KtzUqVOx--t4t2Cn6GnkepPJC4AVGSTF76eHUVXvWo-F7b91lSyYZgyeLlBV1qWf4gbCOmeeUy2ZNQA-ZvzpYTSGX4Hrij_ASH0OwaYjg1jT6XE6Ji2_vKqekVpQvXegT85sgNRqfLeeIUgpTyEkg3ozQ4NG3q2aOzuYNaavTPNrfddSbXeuqOuFgnUNiyPum7FxEj5A7uzmoClHxl0pi_ucuCcb2jUB0ErxeUfG315ctEPtM3Zpr_Ljhn7OvKkyxet5azNOsDRRndbXOYOelAT5WYfGk8LgZ6WjyJb77X0h-PMjxAfZm2B78D3iBosWNTzlpxncVRYw99WSXLejeV-t4-_gdzd0cyTNj_hlODAx4MsuImIs6DYkKF57BMaOhx6SJdJKxX3n2rU2VkaPsqzwDtVzvbCbXfAqorO1Qf7r2C5aYjIFf7XYTyoI71fvJW0CX1B-eNvWyxMxFr8W4ot6Qay7AxF1hglDWonZx2pJAEHDiymyx0lALVWf6-bTi18EqD5VdQrXyHqaAqztxRaCqgRHl7IyKVZbnbRxwY3YCXND3KINJwhAPhWbeQvAjOKmCg0JP5mOjGNkAxIy1GqPlIq3bbXvAm0GXqQ9v4BPEsNvPgf9aOL2bckt6s1MYh_PsXlHQ7tDitxSG8"
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [.authorization(bearerToken: accessToken)
                                ,.init(name: "Content-Type", value: "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                                ,.init(name: "Accept", value: "application/json")
    ]
    AF.request("https://192.168.10.5/api/category/",
               method: .get,
               parameters: nil,
               headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { responseJSON in

        switch responseJSON.result {
        case .success(let value):
            guard
                true
                else {
                    return
                }
            print("")

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Любое значение в accessToken игнорируется.
Подскажите пожалуйста как установить данный заголовок.

Пробовал разные подходы с Alamofire и без, не работает ни один.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо method: .get, method: .post.

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что нужен именно get запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил на стороне сервера, т.к. webservice использует android и windows приложение.
На стороне сервера записываю в заголовок Authorization из X-Access-Token если он не пустой.

P.S. зачем apple запретила использовать данные заголовки мне не понятно. Какой-то маразм.

Позже выяснил, что есть разница между 2мя методами

```
Исправил на стороне сервера, т.к. webservice использует android и windows приложение.
```

На стороне сервера записываю в заголовок Authorization из X-Access-Token если он не пустой.

P.S. зачем apple запретила использовать данные заголовки мне не понятно. Какой-то маразм.

Позже выяснил, что есть разница между 2мя методами

```js
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET" //set http method as POST
//Не рабочий вариант для Authorization
request.addValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

//Необходимо использовать Set подробнее вы можете прочесть перейдя в сам метод
request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```